# Check which graphics cards is being used by Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop. I have two graphics cards: intel and nvidia. How do I check which one is being used by the system?

Thanks

Comment: Run `prime-select query`, assuming the driver is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo -i
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

You should get something like this:

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
```

Where

```
IGD - stands for integrated
DIS - stands for discrete

Pwr - indicates the card is powered on
Off - indicates the card is powered off
+   - indicates the card is active
```

In the example above, my integrated graphics card is active. The example above is also from my Asus N76 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. Some laptops depending on the config only use the discrete graphics card even if they do have an integrated graphics card and in that case the above will not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have both Intel and Nvidia, it is a good idea to have installed the *Nvidia X Server Settings* utility; you can do this from the Ubuntu Software downloader, or do:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

and just do `nvidia-settings` on bash afterwards; or open it by hand. This will allow you to see what card is being used or to select the card you want to use.

Good luck!